# Global replace user input text to modified output by element ID in JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, replace

I am currently learning to use the replace method in JS. I was able to get it to work in a simple function using the console to check the output. However I am now working on making a simple user interface to interact with the function and it has caused some difficulty. I can get the function to accept and re-print the user's text, but the replace portion doesn't seem to be functioning properly as I've written it. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Create a function grabText that replaces the char - with _ -->
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>HMTL Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text"                         id="inputField" 
      placeholder="Input Text"/>
    <button id="clickButton" onclick="grabText();">Run</button>
    <p id="outputText"></p>

   </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var inputText;

function grabText () {
 inputText = document.querySelector("#inputField");
   document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = inputText.value;
  inputText.value.replace(/-/g , "_");
  document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = inputText.value;

}
```

I suspect there is an issue with where and how I am using .value . Thanks for any help.

Comment: Start reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) and  learn how to [debug](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep in mind [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string, it doesn't change the existing one.

```js
var inputText;
function grabText() {
  inputText = document.querySelector("#inputField");
  document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = inputText.value.replace(/-/g, "_");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Input Text" />
<button id="clickButton" onclick="grabText();">Run</button>
<p id="outputText"></p>
```